# Is this sufficient for proving $a^3\equiv a\pmod{3}, a\in\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If $a\in\Bbb{Z}$ then $a^3\equiv a\pmod{3}$.

For the sake of contradiction, assume $a\in\Bbb{Z}$ and $a^3\not\equiv a\pmod{3}$. Then $3\not\mid (a^3-a)$ which implies that either $(a^3-a)=3q+1$ or $(a^3-a)=3q+2$.

Take the case where $(a^3-a)=3q+1$. Then either $q$ is even or odd. If we assume $q$ to be even, then we have $(a^3-a)=3(2n)+1, n\in\Bbb{Z}$ which implies that $(a^3-a)=2(3n)+1$ and therefore $(a^3-a)$ is odd.

But, factoring gives us $(a^3-a)=a(a+1)(a-1)$. Then either $a$ is even or $a$ is odd. But both of these cases show that $(a^3-a)$ would be even. Therefore we have a contradiction.

$\blacksquare$

I'm new to writing proofs so I'm unclear if this single contradiction is sufficient or if it is too narrow of an example.

Comment: You still need to handle the case where $a^3 - a = 3q + 2$.

Comment: The simplest proof is just considering all three cases: $a \equiv 0,1,2 \bmod 3$.

Comment: Another proof is $a^3-a=6\binom{a+1}{3}$ and so $a^3 \equiv a \bmod 6$.

Comment: You could use Fermat's little theorem,  if you know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your proof to work, you’d still need to discard the case where $a^3-a$ is of the form $3k+2$ – the argument will be almost identical. However, your observation that $$a^3-a=a(a+1)(a-1)$$ immediately implies that this expression is always a multiple of three, without needing to resort to a contradiction (since one of three consecutive integers is always a multiple of three). This was exactly what you wanted to prove.